# Multiple Android apps within one xamarin solution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

What is the best way to create multiple Android apps in one Xamarin Form solution?

I've tryed to add a new Android project to my solution, updated my references, packages and MainActivity.cs exactly like the build in .Android project but when I try to run this project I get a System.NullReferenceExeption in the LoadAppliction(new App()); function

Comment: Please show MainActivity code

Comment: using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using MasterDetail;

namespace Huisblad2.Android
{
 [Activity (Label = "Huisblad2", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
 {
  
  protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
  {
   base.OnCreate (bundle);

   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

   LoadApplication (new App());
  }
 }
}

Comment: I'm struggling with my comment markup

Answer (score 0):

i should suggest you to unload other projects while testing one. For example i wrote some preprocessor directives to handle some platform specific codes on my shared codes like

```
#if __IOS__
bla bla
#endif
#if __ANDROID__
bla bla
#endif
```

but even i setup the ios project as start up project, visual studio did not see the **IOS** symbol; which is defined on ios project properties! Than i did unload the android project and everything went well. then i unload my ios project and load android and android project gone well too. I'm not sure your case is something like that but you can give it a try :)